# How to perform groupBy operation in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, group-by

**Angular 2** : 2.0.0-alpha.31 / Typescript 1.5

I requested data from a `http.get` query

```
this.http.get('/data/players.json')
                  .toRx()
                  .map((res) => res.json())
                  .subscribe((data) => {
                        this.players = data;
                  });
```

This query return me this Json object (`this.players`)

```
[
  {"team":"teamA","name":"player1","age":"1"},
  {"team":"teamA","name":"player2","age":"1"},
  {"team":"teamA","name":"player3","age":"1"},
  {"team":"teamB","name":"player4","age":"1"},
  {"team":"teamB","name":"player5","age":"1"}
]
```

Then I would like to display player grouped by team

```
teamA: player1,player2,player3
teamB: player4,player5
```

How can I `groupBy` `team` on **Angular2** (directly into the @View?) ?

**UPDATE**

I saw that on Angular 1, this could be done in the view using `| groupBy:'propertyName'` on ngFor. Is there something like this on Angular 2 ?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure exactly what version of Angular2 it was introduced but you can call [RX's GroupBy function](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/groupby.html). I don't think you need the `.toRx()` call in more recent versions either.

Before you subscribe add something like this:

```
.map((res) => res.json())
.groupBy(
    x => x.team,
    x => x
);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you use filter?

```
var test = [
  {"team":"teamA","name":"player1","age":"1"},
  {"team":"teamA","name":"player2","age":"1"},
  {"team":"teamA","name":"player3","age":"1"},
  {"team":"teamB","name":"player4","age":"1"},
  {"team":"teamB","name":"player5","age":"1"}
];

function FilterByTeam(obj){
    console.log(obj);
    return obj.team === "teamA";
 }

 var teamA = test.filter(FilterByTeam);
 console.log(teamA)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I would like to do it dynamically into a view. I saw that on angular1, this could be done with : `player in players | groupBy: 'team'`, I'm searching something similar. Thanks